# How can a .NET application become a subscriber to a JMS (ActiveMQ) topic?

Tags: .net, jms, activemq-classic

Please lay out the various ways for a .NET application to become a JMS (ActiveMQ) topic subscriber. Detailed and production-quality solutions would of course be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache NMS](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/index.html) is the most complete solution as it's a C# implementation of the OpenWire wire protocol.  Stomp, in my opinion, is a bit too "lightweight" to use in a production-style environment if other options exist.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the articles on this blog regarding ActiveMQ:

http://remark.wordpress.com/?s=activemq

The code there is actually very good. For your specific problem, look at this article:

http://remark.wordpress.com/articles/publish-subscribe-with-activemq-and-nms/